# OpenGL - can't use glew 3.0

Tags: opengl

I've been trying to follow a tutorial of glew, but i can't run this **glGenVertexArrays**, it always leads to a memmory access violation!...

I tried `glExperimental = GL_TRUE` too, also updated my video card driver 2 times, but it doesn't run.

Btw, there's my code (to TRY to generate a simple triangle):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <glew.h>
#include <glfw.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
using namespace glm;

#define GLFW_DLL
//#pragma comment(linker,  "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")
//#pragma comment(linker, "/ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")

int main()
{

    //glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if(!glfwInit())
    {
        cout << "Failed to load graphics... " << endl; 
        return -1;
    }



    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);


    static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = 
    {
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
         0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
    };

    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
    //glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, 0);

    if(!glfwOpenWindow(1024, 768, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, GLFW_WINDOW))
    {
        cout << "Failed to open window";
        glfwTerminate();
        return -2;
    }

    glfwSetWindowTitle("IfUSeeingThisMsgTheShitWorked");

    glfwEnable(GLFW_STICKY_KEYS);

    //Main loop
    do
    {
        cout << "happaned";
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0,3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*) 0);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers();

    }while(glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_ESC) != GLFW_PRESS && glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED));



    return 0;
}
```

Also, I want to point out that this function doesn't work:

```
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

so I had to change it to:

```
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, 0);
```

Does it have anything to do with my error? hm.

I'm posting it here, just to make sure that there's no other thing I can do, other than buy a new video card. 
I really want to use the modern OpenGL, it is pointless to learn the old one.

Comment: AND my card is nvidia 9500, so it should support glew 3.0 but it doesn't...

Comment: Try using a known good example. It's far more likely there's a problem with your code than a hardware problem. Once you've confirmed that it's your code, proceed with debugging it. As it is, I think this question is too localized for the site.

Comment: I would love if its my code, but im following the tutorial... and it compiles. an this problem with GenVertexArrays seems to be very common...

Comment: Download and run the GL extensions viewer (Google for it) & confirm that your hardware/driver actually supports VAOs first.

Comment: :) Just because it compiles doesn't mean much. It's a common problem because it's so easy to write past the bounds of your array. For example, people will often use `sizeof` and get the size of a pointer instead of the size of an array. (not saying that's the case here). You may want to look for similar errors.

Comment: @mh01 Well, it seems that my card supports 3.3, but i have no idea how to check if it supports VAO... So what should i do?

Comment: With 3.3 (3.0 actually, I think) it should support VAOs; also available on older versions with the GL_ARB_vertex_array_object extension.  Never mind that - answer incoming!

Comment: Please stop using GLEW. There are [alternatives that don't have this problem](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually calling glewInit in your code, so you're not even loading the GL entry points.  You should add a call to glewInit *after* your glfwInit call, like so:

```
if(!glfwInit())
{
    cout << "Failed to load graphics... " << endl; 
    return -1;
}

if (glewInit () != GLEW_NO_ERROR)
{
    cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW... " << endl; 
    return -1;
}

// check for required GL_VERSION and extensions here and error out if requirements not met

// and everything else should follow the same as before from here...
GLuint VertexArrayID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);
```

Comment: ...and scooped by Sam!

Comment: Yeah, following the tutorial i didn't notice that there was glfwinit AND glewinit. Very bad mistake, thank you

Comment: Wait, i keep getting the same error, GenVertexArray <- memmory access violation

Comment: Try a glGetString (GL_VERSION) and tell us what it gives you.  I suggest this because if everything else is correct, then the only remaining explanation is that you are getting a downlevel context (possibly Microsoft's software GL1.1 or the equivalent if on another OS); if this is the case then I recommend closing this and opening another question about not getting the correct context level for your hardware.

Answer (score 3):

You're apparently not using Glew at all: you don't initialise the library. It looks like you haven’t even read the first sentence of the first paragraph of the [GLEW documentation](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html).

Another thing you do before even creating the OpenGL context is create a vertex buffer. That cannot work either: [OpenGL doesn’t exist until you create an OpenGL context](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context).

This is the order in which you need to do things:

- Create an OpenGL context (using glfw)
- Initialise GLEW
- Use OpenGL functions